# How to sort by price within a category for e-commerce site

Tags: php, sorting, e-commerce

Im creating an e-commerce site and i got my website to sort by category, name, and price (asc/desc) through if statements. 
I cant seem to figure out how to sort the price or name while im in a category.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  So far, I have a products page with a drop down form, whos action leads to a sort page.  My product data is stored on mySQL.
In my sort page, I attempted to sort both category and name alphabetically with:
if($category && $_POST['product']=='az')
$query = "SELECT id,thumb,name,price,category FROM products WHERE category=$cat ORDER BY name ASC";
This allows me to select both category and name (asc) together, then submit.  That's great, but i want to be able to make all the items in a specific category sort by name while already in the category.